# Installation of npm fails with npm WARN deprecated

Tags: angular, npm-install

Developing .Net 5 and Angular Primang 11 application on Windows 10 and facing difficulties with npm install. Tried many ways but not worked.
Like npm cache clean --force, uninstall and install cli and packages

Following is the CLI versions

```
    Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1100.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.0.4
@schematics/angular          11.0.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1100.5 (cli-only)
```

Following are the errors I am getting:-

```
    npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm ERR! cb() never called!

    npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-22T12_12_10_041Z-debug.log
```

Following is the Package.json

```
{
  "name": "hln",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "testci": "ng test --karma-config karma-ci.conf.js --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "@j2ba/primeng-styles": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-tfs-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^8.0.0-beta.3",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.13",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: The "Errors" or deprecation warnings you get shouldn't cancel the install...they are just warnings of outdated dependencies in one of your packages that you have installed...you should be able to just ignore them

Comment: @MrCodingB its not installing any modules, it stucks at this step for long time.

Comment: Ok...what's the full output that you get, when you let it run through

Comment: @ MrCodingB updated in the question

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: Which version of npm and node are you using? Can you update to the latest?

Comment: @playerone added package.json. Tried with the latest versions of npm and node but doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to clean npm cache

```
 npm cache clean --force
```

Then remove node modules from project and start npm install again?

Comment: this can also be due to incompatible libraries... I also noticed that you are using angular/cdk at version 11 but others are at version 10.

Comment: Also this error means that some library is using  har-validator which not supported. https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/895